# Сегментация изображений, двупроходный алгоритм по ABC-маске, таблица эквивалентности

Tags: алгоритм, сегментация

Есть статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/119244/
в ней сказано, что нужно использовать таблицу эквивалентности в некоторых случаях. Ничего не нашел в интернете по этому вопросу, в других статьях про этот алгоритм тоже мало чего о нем говорится.
Как использовать эту таблицу на втором проходе? Вероятно, нужно объединять, но интуитивные выводы вряд ли понравятся гос. комиссии на защите моей дипломной работы. 
Если знаете где можно об этом почитать, дайте источник.

Comment: http://wiki.technicalvision.ru/index.php/Выделение_и_описание_областей вот тут объясняется, нагуглил по тексту статьи источник: Обработка и анализ цифровых изображений с примерами на LabVIEW IMAQ Vision А. Моржин, А. Ходарев, В. Князь, С. Желтов, Ю. Визильтер